# laravel allowing only authenticated user to access a specific route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have already read this in the official documentation:

Protecting A Route

```
Route::get('profile', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
}));
```

but i couldn't know how to apply it in my case.

This is my routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});


Route::get('index', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});
Route::get('restaurants/admins/{id}', 'RestaurantsController@admins');
Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');
Route::post('admins/login', array('uses' => 'AdminsController@login', 'as' => 'admins.login'));
Route::post('admins/changePicutre', array('uses' => 'AdminsController@changePicture', 'as' => 'admins.changePicture'));
Route::resource('admins', 'AdminsController');
Route::resource('waitingtimes', 'WaitingtimesController');
Route::post('restaurants/changePicture', array('uses' => 'RestaurantsController@changePicture', 'as' => 'restaurants.changePicture'));

Route::get('login', function(){
    return View::make('admins.login');
});
```

I need all the routes to be only for authenticated users except the `loing` route.

could you help me please?

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Route::group()` in order to protect all the routes inside the group with the filter, like so:

```
// All routes in the group are protected, only authed user are allowed to access them
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    Route::get('restaurants/admins/{id}', 'RestaurantsController@admins');

});

// Login, all users allowed
Route::get('login', function(){
    return View::make('admins.login');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('yourRoutes', array('before' => 'auth', function()
{
// Only authenticated users may enter...
}));


Route::get('routes',array('before'=>'auth','as'=>'namedRoute','uses'=>'controller');
```

Comment: do you mean to put the routes inside the `function` ??

Comment: do you mean change `Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController');` to `Route::resource('restaurants', 'RestaurantsController', array('before' => 'auth', function(){}));` ??

Answer (score 0):

For `Laravel 5.4 +` You can use the below code

For Single route

```
Route::get('home',[HomeController::class,"index"])->middleware(['auth']);
```

For Multiple Routes or group of routes

```
Route::prefix('user')
->middleware(['auth'])
->group(function () {
    Route::get('profile',[ProfileController::class,'manageProfile']);
    Route::get('manage-password', [ManagePasswordController::class, 'manageProfile']);
});
```